# How to run a tests suite that comes in a sdist?

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, pip, sdist

I would like to be able to run the tests suite when "mypackage" has been installed via `pip`.

I have created the `mypackage-version.tar.gz` file myself, using `python setup.py sdist`. `mypackage-version.tar.gz` does contain the `tests/` directory (moreover, the `.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` inside it does list all files under `tests/` too).

But after I've run `pip install mypackage-version.tar.gz` inside a dedicated brand new virtual environment, there is no `tests/` directory anywhere in the virtual environment:

```
$ find ./myvenv/ -name "*tests*"
./myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/webencodings/__pycache__/tests.cpython-36.pyc
./myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/_vendor/webencodings/tests.py
```

Reading `pip` documentation or the output of `pip install --help`, I just can't figure out if there's any way to ask `pip` to install the tests correctly along the rest.

I've also tried to unpack the `tests/` directory manually (along with `pytest.ini`), but the tests do not start because `pytest` complains about not finding `mypackage` module (`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypackage'`), even if both `pytest` and `mypackage` show up in `pip list`... and both are the ones from the virtual environment (as `which` command tells), as well as `pip` and `python` (that can `import mypackage`).

Yet manually unpacking looks hacky, so before digging further into this, I'd liked to know what is the right way to go: using `pip`? Manually unpacking? Anything else? Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: finally, I could run the manually unpacked tests using `python -m pytest`. But this remains a workaround, and I'd still liked to know whether there's a more proper (and automated) way to install and run the tests suite

Comment: This link may be helpful: https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html

Comment: @StanislavIvanov thanks, even if that does not answer my question, it's an interesting reading on that topic